# Slicing two arrays with number and steps then merge them

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I am struggling to put these positions of spheres (with different diameters) inside the box:

```
import numpy as np

    data1 = np.linspace([-451.0,-451.0,-451.0], [451.0,451.0,451.0], 2940)
    
    data2 = np.linspace([-376.0,-376.0,-376.0], [376.0,376.0,376.0], 21)
```

a) I want to make sure that starts and ends are 3d arrays, as the arrays represent positions inside a box.

b)I want to specify a step for every number as 4 for 2940
and 150 for 21

c)I want to merge them into one array-I was thinking of filtering by a function if I have  a step (len)-

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Comment: I think a), b) and c) illustrate my question

Comment: @ZeinabMardi I have upgraded numpy to 1.20.1, but still does not have step.